# What are the rules for filename matching initWithNibName?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, xib

initWithNibName on iOS is clever: it does things like automatically load different NIB for iPad instead of iPhone (although lots of people don't know this - it IS NOT DOCUMENTED in UIViewController.initWithNibName!).

But what else can it do? The only Apple docs I've found for this explain that:

1. It will look for and find files with ~ipad or ~iphone on the end of the name
2. Apple *implies* that it follows the rules for automatic image filename matching

But there's no link to the rules for image matching, and I can't find any explicit docs for either :(.

Rules might include: "you get a different NIB for retina if you put @2x on the end of the filename" (I have no idea if this works).

What I'm really looking for is a list of what rules ARE used. It would save a lot of hardcoding - repeated in almost every single app I write - if I could make more use of their intelligent name matching (e.g. if they have a "load landscape nib vs. load portrait nib")

Comment: Great question! I didn't even know about the `~iphone` and `~ipad` matching, since Apple doesn't seem to make use of this in their own template code! I'll be watching this question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your (main) question, these are the rules for filename matching in `initWithNibName`:

> ...However, if you do not specify a nib name, and do not override the
>   loadView method in your custom subclass, the view controller searches
>   for a nib file using other means. Specifically, it looks for a nib
>   file with an appropriate name (without the .nib extension) and loads
>   that nib file whenever its view is requested. Specifically, it looks
>   (in order) for a nib file with one of the following names:
>
> 1. If the view controller class name ends with the word “Controller”, as in MyViewController, it looks for a nib file whose name matches the
>      class name without the word “Controller”, as in MyView.nib.
> 2. It looks for a nib file whose name matches the name of the view
>      controller class. For example, if the class name is
>      MyViewController, it looks for a MyViewController.nib file.
>
> *From UIViewController's documentation under **nibName***

But there is more... Actually the `NSBundle` have some pretty smart rules for locating resources inside it. [Here is the documentation page describing these rules](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFOundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/AccessingaBundlesContents/AccessingaBundlesContents.html)
(see: *Device-Specific Resources in iOS*).

Which brings us [to this page](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html) that describes all the modifiers (and the basic pattern) that can be applied to bundle resources (this I believe is the link you're mentioning regarding image filename matching).

Comment: So ... reading those links ... there are NO specific rules for NIB files? They inherit the "basic" rule for all resources (link 1), but have NO additional rules (link2) - correct?

Comment: Yes that would be correct. One more thing I could add is the `smart` loading of nib files based on localization. Since this is a really interesting topic, anyone who can add more information would be really welcome.